# Find matching one, two or three word phrases in a string in R

Tags: r, string, extract

I am trying to identify, match and extract two-word phrases within a char column of strings in a dataframe in R.

I have a sample list of terms such as:

```
phrases <- as.list(c("Business","Business Process", "Processes", "Business Processes"))
```

and a string like:

```
string <- "brings seamless integration among the business processes and financials."
```

I am using str_extract_all and sapply like this:

```
sapply(str_extract_all(tolower(string), paste(tolower(phrases), collapse = "|")), function(s) paste(s, collapse=', '))
```

Which is only identifying the single word terms and not the two-word phrase "business processes" which is needed as well.

The current output is: [1] "business, processes"

But I want to be able to get "business, processes, business processes"

I have tried using the patterns \\b and adding a \\s in between the two-word phrase but it didn't help.

How should I go about extracting both the one and two-word phrases?

**EDIT:**
I need to retain the matches as a column within the dataframe - I tried the below three suggestions and am getting the following error:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, phrases, value = c("business", "process",  : 
  replacement has 267 rows, data has 495

My DataFrame has multiple columns with one column containing the strings to match against the phrases list. I need to be able to pull all the matches in as a comma seperated values within the same row of the string. Desired output

```
Row,   String,                                  Phrases
1,  Businesses are great,                       business
2,  Great thing are great, 
3,   Processes are great,                       processes
4,   Business Processes are great for business, business processes, processes, business
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grepl`:

```
unlist(phrases[sapply(phrases, function(x) grepl(paste0("\\<", x, "\\>"), string, ignore.case = T))])
#[1] "Business"           "Processes"          "Business Processes"
```

or for all lower case:

```
unlist(tolower(phrases)[sapply(tolower(phrases), function(x) grepl(paste0("\\<", x, "\\>"), tolower(string)))])
#[1] "business"           "processes"          "business processes"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
tmp <- sapply(phrases,function(x) regmatches(string,gregexpr(paste0("\\b",x,"\\b"),string,ignore.case = T)))
 > unlist(tmp)
[1] "business"           "processes"          "business processes"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unname(mapply(function(x,y)str_extract(x,paste0(tolower(y),"\\b")),string,phrases))
[1] "business"           NA                   "processes"          "business processes"
```